# Car dealership branding their cars

Tags: body, dealer

Do all car dealerships brand their cars? By branding I mean putting the dealer's name usually next to the model decal on the car. I find this very annoying - I don't want to put bumper stickers on my new car, and I definitely don't want a non-removable dealership ad on there.

If I asked them to not put that on my new car, would they think I am strange?

Answer (score 7):

The dealerships I worked at would take it off at the request of the customer. It's simple you're the customer and the salesman isn't going to lose a sale over the sticker. If you have already bought the car or just aren't comfortable asking them to do it you can DIY by following [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/610/85).

Answer (score 5):

Most do, yes - It is free advertising for them. Round here it is usually a sticker in the rear window, but I have seen some dealers put something on the back panel. They also put their details on the licence plate (a legal requirement in the UK for anyone supplying plates)

I suspect that if you asked them not to, the sales person would say "Yeah, sure", then they'd ignore your wishes and stick it on anyway... If it is just a sticker you may be able to remove it with some care and "sticky stuff remover"

Comment: You can do what my dad always did: "Then put it in the sales agreement."  If they branded the car at that point, he walked away.

Comment: I don't worry about it.  They peel off easy enough.  I wouldn't walk away from a car I wanted just because I'd have to invest 30 seconds labor peeling off a label.  :-)